# Calling the column values when the column names are date macro variables

Tags: date, sas, multiple-columns, sas-macro

In SAS, I have a dataset which has 5 columns and 4 rows. The column names are date macro variables.

I want to subtract the values in one column from another. (Date of column 4 - date of column 3) doesn't work. This subtracts the date itself and not the values in those columns.

How do I call the values of the columns?

Please help.

Example--  There are five columns-12/1/2019,12/1/2020,12/1/2021,12/1/2022   12/1/2023 and four rows-A,B,C,D and some values are stored in them.

In the above table, I want to add a column which prints the difference between the values on all dates for all the rows (A,B,C,D).

Also sim_date= 12/1/20, f_starting=12/1/2019, f_1=12/1/2021, f_2=12/1/2022, f_3=12/1/2023. These dates are all macro variables.

But when I write the code as

``````
             data test;
             set test;
             format g0 g1 g2 g3 percent5.2 ;
             g0 = (&sim_date - &f_starting)/&f_starting;
             g1 = (&f_1 - &sim_date)/&sim_date  ;
             g2 = (&f_2 - &f_1)/&f_1  ;
             g3 = (&f_3- &f_2)/&f_2 ; 
             run; 
`````
This code subtracts the two dates instead of the values stored in the dates. How do I call the values?
``````

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide the `test` set that you have. Are the columns all numeric? Why do you call macro-variables in your code?

Comment: test just contained the data with the dates on the rows. I transposed it to make it as columns. Yes, all the columns are numeric. sim_date is something which I take from the user. And then make a dataset called 'dates' which stores the dates f_starting=sim_date-1year, f_1= sim_date+1 year , f_2= sim_date +2 years. So I have called macro variables in the code since the dates will change according to what sim_date the user enters.

Comment: `12/1/20` is not normally a valid name for a variable.  Are you sure the variables are using such strange names?  Perhaps you are looking at the LABEL of the variable instead of its name?  Did you accidentally set the VALIDVARNAME option to ANY so that SAS actually creates and allows such strange strings as variable names?  Can you start over with VALIDVARNAME set to V7 instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "date macro variables"?  Macro variables contain text.  Do you mean the text they contain looks to humans like dates?

Comment: Show a proc contents of your input data set. FYI - testing using `data test; set test;` is bad practice and makes it very hard to debug and test your code. Use unique names.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `"varname"n` syntax so that SAS knows you are referring to the variable instead of the value.

```
data test;
set test;
format g0 g1 g2 g3 percent5.2 ;
g0 = ("&sim_date"n - "&f_starting"n)/"&f_starting"n;
g1 = ("&f_1"n - "&sim_date"n)/"&sim_date"n  ;
g2 = ("&f_2"n - "&f_1"n)/"&f_1"n  ;
g3 = ("&f_3"n - "&f_2"n)/"&f_2"n ; 
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You reference a variable by its name.  So if your variables are named sim_date and f_starting then your code might be:

```
g0 = (sim_date - f_starting)/f_starting;
```

If your variables are actually using those non-standard names that start with digits or have slashes or other non standard characters in them then you need to use a name literal.  That is a quoted string suffixed with the letter n.  So if the variables are named `2022/01/01` and `2022/02/01` for the first days of the first two months of 2022 then your code needs to look like:

```
g0 = ("2022/02/01"n - "2022/01/01"n)/"2022/01/01"n;
```

So either set the macro variables to name literals.

```
%let sim_date="2022/02/01"n;
%let f_starting="2022/02/01"n;
```

and then your current code will work.

```
g0 = (&sim_date - &f_starting)/&f_starting;
```

Or leave your macro variables with strings that match the actual variable names and convert them to name literals when you use them in your code:

```
%let sim_date = 2022/02/01;
%let f_starting = 2022/01/01;
g0 = ("&sim_date"n - "&f_starting"n)/"&f_starting"n;
```